# Mongoose ObjectID as Object key and then populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, objectid

I want to generate a dynamic object with the keys as the objectID of another model and then populate the dynamic keys. eg for an asset, I want the details keys to be an attribute ID but when populating the details I want the keys to be attribute.name instead of _id

```
attributes:
{
    "_id":"5a23f5e6159f5c3438c75971",
    "name": "name"
    "type": "string"
}
{
    "_id":"5a23f60b159f5c3438c75972",
    "name": "age"
    "type": "number"
}

asset: 
{
    "_id":"5a23f5e6159f5c3438c75973",
    "type": "driver",
    "details": {
        "5a23f5e6159f5c3438c75971": "bob",
        "5a23f60b159f5c3438c75972": "50",
    }
}

populated asset: 
{
    "type": "driver",
    "details": {
        "name": "bob",
        "age": "50",
    }
}


const Attribute = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["string", "number", "mobile", "email"],
    }
})

const Asset = new Schema({
    type: { type: String },
    details: { [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Attribute"}]: String }
})
```

I can define details as `details: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed }` and then push in the object with attribute id as key but I am not able to figure out how to populate them and how to define the asset schema correctly to enable this. Appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: You have to save the object ID of the document of the other collection which you want to refer to in the field where `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId`. You can call `.populate('collectionName')` to populate when doing a search

Comment: yes I know how populate works, what I am trying is not a standard implementation hence the question here.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't really do that. What you are trying to do is you're essentially changing the 'field name' dynamically which is not supported through population

Comment: hmm ok. i will probably change details from object to array in that case and store it as array of key, value objects where the key will be the _id which can be populated and transformed from _id to attribute name. Unless there is a magical solution that pops up

Comment: Let's see how it works